# Why does translation matrix not affect rendering of 3d model in python?

Tags: python, matrix, 3d

I am very new to coding and decided to start with a 3D engine in python. I followed OLC's tutorial and adapted it for python. However, my translation matrix doesn't seem to be affecting how the model is rendered. Any advice at all, from code improvements, to telling me how bad I am would be much appreciated.

I have tried to re-do the vector multiplication in all sorts of ways, and all kinds of reformatting and re-trying, but I am not even sure what I am looking for in this case. Any help would be much appreciated

As I am new, I apologize for any poor etiquette I may have done on this site.

```
import math, numpy as np, pygame, sys, os, random, string
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
width,height = 1600,900;cx,cy = width//2,height//2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 18)
pygame.display.set_caption('3D Graphics')

def loadObj(filename):
    tris = []
    verts = []
    try:
        fp = open(filename, "r")
    except:
        print("File: "+filename+" not found")
        sys.exit(1)
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values: continue
        if values[0] == 'v':
            #v = vec3(float(values[1]), float(values[2]), float(values[3]))
            #verts.append(vec3(int(values[1]), int(values[2]), int(values[3])))
            verts.append(vec3(float(values[1]), float(values[2]), float(values[3]), 0 ))
            #verts.append(v)
        elif values[0] == 'f':
            p = []
            for v in values[1:]:
                w = v.split("/")
                p.append(int(w[0]))
                #print(p)


            #print(verts[-185])
            triTemp = triangle(verts[p[0] - 1], verts[p[1] - 1], verts[p[2]- 1])
            tris.append(triTemp)
            
    fp.close()
    return tris

class vec3():                                       #Possibly Obsolete
    __slots__ = ['x','y','z','w']
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, w):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.w = w
class triangle():
    __slots__ = ['vec1','vec2','vec3']
    def __init__(self, vec1, vec2, vec3):
        self.vec1 = vec1
        self.vec2 = vec2
        self.vec3 = vec3

def matrixMakeTranslation(x, y, z):
    
    matrix = np.zeros((4,4))
    matrix[0,0] = 1.0
    matrix[1,1] = 1.0
    matrix[2,2] = 1.0
    matrix[3,3] = 1.0
    matrix[3,0] = x
    matrix[3,1] = y
    matrix[3,2] = z
    return matrix

def Matrix_MakeRotationX(fAngleRad):
    matrix = np.zeros((4,4))
    matrix[0,0] = 1.0
    matrix[1,1] = (math.cos(fAngleRad * 0.5))
    matrix[1,2] = (math.sin(fAngleRad * 0.5))
    matrix[2,1] = (-math.sin(fAngleRad * 0.5))
    matrix[2,2] = (math.cos(fAngleRad * 0.5))
    matrix[3,3] = 1.0
    return matrix

def Matrix_MakeRotationZ(fAngleRad):

    matrix = np.zeros((4,4))
    matrix[0,0] = (math.cos(fAngleRad))
    matrix[0,1] = (math.sin(fAngleRad))
    matrix[1,0] = (-math.sin(fAngleRad))
    matrix[1,1] = (math.cos(fAngleRad))
    matrix[2,2] = 1.0
    matrix[3,3] = 1.0
    return matrix

fNear = float(0.1)                                                      #Create the Projection Matrix
fFar = float(1000.0)
fFov = float(90.0)
fAspectRatio = float(height/width)
fFovRad = 1/math.tan(fFov * 0.5 / 180 * math.pi)

projectionMatrix = np.zeros((4,4))
projectionMatrix[0,0] = fAspectRatio * fFovRad
projectionMatrix[1,1] = fFovRad
projectionMatrix[2,2] = fFar / (fFar - fNear)
projectionMatrix[3,2] = float((-fFar * fNear) / (fFar - fNear))
projectionMatrix[2,3] = 1.0
projectionMatrix[3,3] = 0.0

meshname = "teapot.obj"                                               #Load the mesh
tris = loadObj(meshname)


vCamera = np.array([0,0,0,0])
fAngleRad = 0

colour = (255,255,255)
colour2 = (0,0,0)

triProjected = triangle(np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]))           #These are used later
triTranslalted = triangle(np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]))
triTransformed= triangle(np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0,0]))
while True:                                                                                             #Begin Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():                                                                    #Quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
    dt = clock.tick()/1000
    pygame.display.set_caption('3D Graphics - FPS: %.2f'%int(dt))
    print("fps:", clock.get_fps())                                                                      #Framerate and caption
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    fAngleRad += 0.1
    matRotZ = Matrix_MakeRotationZ(fAngleRad * 0.5)                                                     #Set up matricies
    matRotX = Matrix_MakeRotationX(fAngleRad)
    matTrans = matrixMakeTranslation(0.0,0.0,50.0)
    matWorld = np.identity(4)
    matWorld = matRotZ @ matRotX
    matWorld = matWorld @ matTrans                                                                      #Seems to be broken. idk why.

    for i in tris:                                                                                      #For triangle in all triangles

        reDo1 = np.array([i.vec1.x, i.vec1.y, i.vec1.z, i.vec1.w])
        reDo2 = np.array([i.vec2.x, i.vec2.y, i.vec2.z, i.vec2.w])
        reDo3 = np.array([i.vec3.x, i.vec3.y, i.vec3.z, i.vec3.w])

        triTransformed.vec1 = np.matmul(matWorld, reDo1)
        triTransformed.vec2 = np.matmul(matWorld, reDo2)
        triTransformed.vec3 = np.matmul(matWorld, reDo3)

        triProjected.vec1 = np.matmul(projectionMatrix, triTransformed.vec1)
        triProjected.vec2 = np.matmul(projectionMatrix, triTransformed.vec2)
        triProjected.vec3 = np.matmul(projectionMatrix, triTransformed.vec3)

        #Scale Into View
        triProjected.vec1[0] += 1.0
        triProjected.vec1[1] += 1.0
        
        triProjected.vec2[0] += 1.0
        triProjected.vec2[1] += 1.0
        
        triProjected.vec3[0] += 1.0
        triProjected.vec3[1] += 1.0

        triProjected.vec1[0] *= 0.5 * width
        triProjected.vec1[1] *= 0.5 * height
        
        triProjected.vec2[0] *= 0.5 * width
        triProjected.vec2[1] *= 0.5 * height
        
        triProjected.vec3[0] *= 0.5 * width
        triProjected.vec3[1] *= 0.5 * height

            
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, colour, [(triProjected.vec1[0], triProjected.vec1[1]),(triProjected.vec2[0], triProjected.vec2[1]),(triProjected.vec3[0], triProjected.vec3[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Homogenious Coordinates to represent the vertices of your model. So the W component must be 1.

When you load your model you are setting W to 0.

```
verts.append(vec3(float(values[1]), float(values[2]), float(values[3]), 0 ))
```

By setting W=0 you are creating a Homogenious Vector (a.k.a "point at infinity" or "ideal point") and by setting W=1 you are creating a Homogeneous Point.

Points can be translated but vectors cannot.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, you were exactly right and I messed up there; i wasn't thinking. However, it didn't seem to help. I would normally try to figure this out by myself, but I am still lost and would appreciate any other advice you could give.

Comment: Can you describe what you see? What is exactly wrong?

Comment: Changing "matTrans = matrixMakeTranslation(0.0,0.0,50.0)" Doesn't seem to affect how the model is rendered; its the same problem I was having before, even after implementing your fix. I appreciate all the help you're giving me.

Comment: The function matrixMakeTranslation should have:
    matrix[0,3] = x
    matrix[1,3] = y
    matrix[2,3] = z
Because it is column major. And the order of the multiplication for matWorld should be: matWorld = matTrans @ matRotX @ matRotZ. Finally I think the projection is wrong. The projection operation involves the division by W coordinate (or Z coordinate depending on projection model) but that's not present in your code.

Comment: I've implemented these fixes, but I still cannot offset the position of the model with matMakeTranslation, even after implementing your fixes. I have an older version that doesnt use numpy that works well, but it also doesn't implement the w axis, so there may be somewhere it's still a vector or something. Please help me

Comment: I just double checked, and the x and y value seem to offset the model just fine, but the z value doesnt put the model further from the camera for some reason. very odd. I cant find the bug but im searching

Comment: That's probably because of the projection transform. You can only see changes in depth direction when you use Perspective projection. As your code is not dividing by W (or Z), your projection is Orthogonal. Orthogonal projection don't take into account the Z value.

Comment: How would I implement perspective projection into my code? I apologize for the dumb question, but I do not understand it very well. Again, thank you for the help. I feel very grateful

Comment: Your peojection matrix should be column major as well, so you need to set projectionMatrix[3,2] = 1 and projectionMatrix[2,3] = to what was in (3,2). Then after multiply your point with projection matrix you need to divide x, y and z by w. Check out this link for a more accurate projection matrix and explanation of the involved math https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/

Comment: Link was very helpful! Got it working now! Thank you very much for all your help. I know it doesnt add to the conversation, but I just had to say it as I jumped out of my chair yelling "YES!". Thank you so much sir Mauricio.